# Right Side buttons in ActionBar are not working in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

> I am having 3 buttons in ActionBar. one is in Left and using it to
>   call an another activity as a drawer. Another two buttons are in Right
>   side of Actionbar But they are not working.

Here is my Menu file:-

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.bottomtabs.FirstActivity" >


   <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/like"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:title="menu_settings"/> 

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="Search"
          android:icon="@drawable/notifications"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>


</menu>
```

> Here is my Activity in which I am using it.

```
 public class FirstActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
    String getselectevalue;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bottom_tabs);


        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(this);
        // mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),
        // R.id.menu_settings);

        getselectevalue = getIntent().getExtras().getString("selectedVlaue");

        Log.d("got the value here", getselectevalue);

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("key", "Simple");
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Post").setIndicator("Post"),Fragment1.class, b);
        //
        //mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Post").setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.post_selected),FirstActivity.class));

        b = new Bundle();
        System.out.print("hello git");
        b.putString("key", "Contacts");
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Profile").setIndicator("Profile"),Fragment2.class, b);
        b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("key", "Custom");
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Chat").setIndicator("Chat"),Fragment3.class, b);

        b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("key", "Custom");
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Event").setIndicator("Event"),Fragment3.class, b);

        b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("key", "Custom");
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Shop").setIndicator("Shop"),Fragment3.class, b);
        // setContentView(mTabHost);

        if(getselectevalue.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){

        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

        }else{

            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        switch (itemId) {
        case android.R.id.home:

             Toast.makeText(this, "home pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             Intent slide = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,Slide.class);

             startActivity(slide);
             overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);

            break;
        case R.id.action_settings:

             Toast.makeText(this, "plzzzz start working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            break;


        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setEnabled(true);

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
     super.onBackPressed();
     overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    }


}
```

Please Help me to sort it out. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Rename `onMenuItemSelected()` to `onOptionsItemSelected()`.</strike>

Replace your `onMenuItemSelected()` with an `onOptionsItemSelected()` method. This will involve removing the `int featureId` parameter in addition to renaming the method.

Comment: is it just renaming though, isnt the method signature different too?

Comment: yes its because the arguments to the method `onOptionsItemsSelected()` is different, I believe its `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` you need to be overriding that method instead of `onMenuItemSelected` I think its because post android 3.0, there has been a change in the semantics of the action bar, the UI element that used to be referred to as the Menu, was now action overflow, I think hence the change in the method naming too, not sure about this though

Comment: @bhargav, when I replaced the method, first thing android asked to me is remove override notation.

Comment: @Devraj yes its not about just renaming the method, you need to change its arguments types too and then put back the `@Override` as `onOptionsItemSelected` is the activity's on menu options selected event listener

Comment: @CommonsWare could you possibly verify if what I said in the previous comment true about the method name getting changed because of the action bar semantics getting changed from using menu to using actions? I'm not quite sure would like to know if thats actually the case. If yes then maybe I can post a complete answer of my own

Comment: @Bhargav: `onOptionsItemSelected()` has always been the method name. They kept the name (despite the switch to an "action bar") for backwards compatibility reasons. I have never seen anyone implement `onMenuItemSelected()` and am not aware of any sample code, books, blog posts, etc. that advocate its use.

Comment: @Bhargav both are some, it makes no changes. may be in my case only.. :(

Comment: and brother when I remove the Break from between both switch cases, BOth toast msgs works when I press drawer button.. :P

Comment: Also replace `return true`  in  `onOptionItemSelected` method with `return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);`

Comment: @Devraj: "and brother when I remove the Break from between both switch cases, BOth toast msgs works when I press drawer button" -- that is the way `switch` works in Java. Beyond that, there are countless examples of using `onOptionsItemSelected()` for the action bar, as that's pretty much all anyone ever uses. See [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ActionBarDemoNative), for example.

Comment: @Devraj "and brother when I remove the Break from between both switch cases, BOth toast msgs works when I press drawer button." then that means `itemId` is neither equalto `android.R.id.home` (Idk why you are using an internal android namespace id, could cause problems in the future) nor `R.id.action_settings`

Comment: @Devraj Also as I can see from your Layout file, there is not a single item with id = android.R.id.home

Comment: @Bhargav: `android.R.id.home` is from the home icon on `Theme.Holo`-based themes. Also, the way both `case` blocks will be executed is if the first one matches and does not have a `break`, causing execution to continue into the second `case`. If none of the `case` conditions match, then none are executed.

Comment: @Bhargav, Exactly, what I actually want to tell you that home is coming from  this " getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);" I called this in the activity class. and other buttons in menu.
ByTheWay, I tried your solution but it remain same.

Comment: yes I misread and misunderstood a few things sorry its quite late here atm, yes if both toasts are executed then I suppose the home button works, I'd like to `android:orderInCategory="100"` why you have that though you don't have 100 items in that menu, also shouldn't you have the showAsAction attribute specified too?

Comment: @Bhargav, android:orderInCategory="100" is just writen over there, I didnt remove that line from the initial code. this line doesnt matter till we have enough space to put the item in actionbar.we can remove it too. Now, the showAsAction, I am trying all the things, as by removing, setting that always, never..... But nothing is working in my case. as you can see in next two button I am having this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> Initially It was too complicated to understand but after a brief
>   discussion with @BHARGAV and @COMMONSWARE, I tried to understand the
>   behavior of Actionbar and Menu. I did some changes in my code that
>   started working like a charm for me.

Here is the change I have made in my code.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
    case android.R.id.home:

         Toast.makeText(this, "home pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         Intent slide = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,Slide.class);

         startActivity(slide);
         overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);
         return true;


    case R.id.menu_settings:

         Toast.makeText(this, "plzzzz start working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    menu.findItem(R.id.menu_settings).setEnabled(true);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```